# Setting up a nested field in Word using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word, word-field

I am building a large document in pieces from templates. Each template has a keyword `#OVERALLPAGENUMBER#` in the footer which I am programmatically replacing (using Excel VBA) with a field.

If all I needed were that document's page number, the following would suffice:

```
Dim storyRange As Object 'Word.Range
For Each storyRange In oDoc.StoryRanges
    Do
        With storyRange.Find
            .Text = "#OVERALLPAGENUMBER#"
            .Wrap = 1 'wdFindContinue
            .Execute
            While .found
                storyRange.Fields.Add Range:=storyRange, Type:=-1, Text:="PAGE", PreserveFormatting:=True
                .Execute
            Wend
        End With
        On Error Resume Next
        Set storyRange = storyRange.NextStoryRange
        On Error GoTo 0
    Loop While Not storyRange Is Nothing
Next
```

I've tested this code, and it successfully puts the page number in the footer. What I want, however, is a nested (formula) field which adds a fixed number to the page number so that I can display a page count across multiple documents. My solution, if I do it manually (using Ctrl+F9), gives field codes that look like this:

```
{ = 5 + { PAGE } }
```

And correctly produces "6" on page 1, "7" on page 2, etc...

No matter what I try though, I cannot replicate this sort of field nesting using VBA. (Macro recorder is useless here). Can anyone find a way to create these fields programmatically?

---

**Solution**

My problem was that having `PreserveFormatting:=True` was getting in the way of my attempts to nest one field within the other. Now the following simple solution works:

```
With storyRange.Find
    .Text = "#POLICYPAGENO#"
    .Wrap = 1 'wdFindContinue
    .Execute
    While .found
        storyRange.Select
        With oDoc.ActiveWindow
            .Selection.Fields.Add Range:=.Selection.Range, Type:=-1, Text:="PAGE", PreserveFormatting:=False
            .Selection.MoveLeft Unit:=1, Count:=1, Extend:=1
            .Selection.Fields.Add Range:=.Selection.Range, Type:=-1, PreserveFormatting:=False
            .Selection.TypeText Text:="= " & OverallPageNumber & " +"
        End With
        .Execute
    Wend
End With
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that your method of Find and Replacing will Select the text `#OVERALLPAGENUMBER#` each time it loops through.  If that is the case you can replace `storyRange.Fields.Add Range:=storyRange, Type:=-1, Text:="PAGE", PreserveFormatting:=True` with the following, which will simply place your required field code at the current selection:

```
Selection.Fields.Add Range:=Selection.Range, Type:=wdFieldEmpty, PreserveFormatting:=False
Selection.TypeText Text:="= 5 +"
Selection.Fields.Add Range:=Selection.Range, Type:=wdFieldEmpty, PreserveFormatting:=False
Selection.TypeText Text:="PAGE"
Selection.Fields.Update
```

Edit: The previous code only works if `PreserveFormatting` is set to `False`.  It appears that Word updates an empty field code if `PreserveFormatting` is set to `True`.  You can navigate the selection to keep the formatting with the following.   You should only need to `PreserveFormatting` for the outer field.

```
Selection.Fields.Add Range:=Selection.Range, Type:=wdFieldEmpty, PreserveFormatting:=True
Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1, Extend:=wdExtend
Selection.Fields.ToggleShowCodes
Selection.MoveLeft Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
Selection.TypeText Text:="= 5 +"
Selection.Fields.Add Range:=Selection.Range, Type:=wdFieldEmpty, PreserveFormatting:=False
Selection.TypeText Text:="PAGE"
Selection.Fields.Update
```

Comment: Well, my find method did not automatically select the text, so that didn't work off the bat. I then modified your code to first execute `storyRange.Select` but even then, all that code ended up doing was inserting two blank fields around plain text resulting in `{ \* MERGEFORMAT }= 5 +{ \* MERGEFORMAT }PAGE`

Comment: Ok, so you just need to move the `Selection` to inside the Field Code after the first field is added following your `storyRange.Select`.  It's a bit hard without seeing your document but something like `Selection.MoveLeft Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1`.  It may not have worked because of the `\* MERGEFORMAT`, let me look.

Comment: Please see the updated answer.  I believe this should work if you use `storyRange.Select` now.

Comment: PreserveFormatting was what was killing me! Cheers

Comment: Good stuff.  Yeah Word can be unpredictable like those two sample show and the code ugly when you have to move around the document to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 5):

I know this is old, but trying to do this yesterday, I found a simpler solution to creating nested fields than to use the Selection object.  The only solutions I found on the web incorrectly say that there's no way to insert nested fields without using the Selection object.  However, I found that you can insert a nested field into the Field.Code range, which makes the code easier to manipulate, faster and more intuitive. As in:

```
Dim storyRange As Object 'Word.Range
For Each storyRange In oDoc.StoryRanges
    Do
        With storyRange.Find
            .Text = "#OVERALLPAGENUMBER#"
            .Wrap = 1 'wdFindContinue
            .Execute
            While .Found
                Set fld1 = storyRange.Fields.Add(Range:=storyRange, Type:=-1, Text:="=p+" & OverallPageNumber, PreserveFormatting:=False)
                Set fld2 = storyRange.Fields.Add(Range:=fld1.Code.Characters(3), Type:=-1, Text:="PAGE", PreserveFormatting:=False)
                fld1.Update
                .Execute
            Wend
        End With
        On Error Resume Next
        Set storyRange = storyRange.NextStoryRange
        On Error GoTo 0
    Loop While Not storyRange Is Nothing
Next
```

Comment: That works for me! Very much thanks! This should be accepted!

Comment: Yes, very neat, many thanks! Just one caveat, seems if fld1.ShowCodes happes to be True when adding fld2, then fld1.Code.Characters Count is always 1 (no matter how long .Code.Text really is), so .Code.Characters(3) (as for example) will error out ("member of collection not found"). So to be safe I'm preceding fld2 creation with fld1.ShowCodes = False.