# How can I determine the page number of a field in MS Word with VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-word, field, page-numbering

I am using the QR-Code DISPLAYBARCODE field. I am updating all DISPLAYBARCODE with some information like date and time, additionaly I want to add the page number on which the DISPLAYBARCODE field is.

For tables I would use the range field but this is not available for fields.

Is there a way how to do that?

Answer (score 2):

If you want the page number to display as part of the QR Code, you could embed a page field in the text of the code. Something like:

- { DisplayBarCode "{ Date } { Time } Page { Page }" QR \s  100 \r  0 \q  3 }

Note the quotation marks. They are necessary.

*The DATE and TIME fields are the date and time when the document is printed or those fields are updated. They are not fixed timestamps.*

---

I am working on the code for you to enter a field like the one shown.

- Is that what you want?
- Do you want to have the page, date, and time appear inside the DisplayBarCode field so that they show up when the bar code is read?
- Do you instead of the current date and time want a time stamp for when the code is run?
- What else goes in the field? The current content? Before or after the date, time and page?

Take a look at the second answer in this thread (from WillWillPower): [Setting up a nested field in Word using VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15338309/setting-up-a-nested-field-in-word-using-v)

```
It uses the range of the field code.
```